# Mysql byte array storage

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arrays, binaryfiles

I have a byte array created in Java. It represents content of some file. I don't know exactly the maximum size of this array. It can be different sizes. I want to store it in mysql. What type should I use in mysql?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), `medium blob` , [`varbinary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html)

[Mysql Choosing the Right Type for a Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/choosing-types.html)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`varbinary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) to store byte arrays of arbitrary length in MySQL.

Comment: if I use varbinary, what java type should I use for java mapping of the field when i do select? byte[] or string?

Comment: @user1379574 use `byte[]` (here is a [link](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/mapping-mysql-data-types-in-java.shtml) that lists type mappings).

Answer (score 1):

use a `blob` field

[java serialblob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html)

[mysql blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/blob.html)