# Can you store bytes (Fernet token) in a MySQL table? python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, cryptography

I am trying to insert this Fernet encrypted token into my table in my database. It is encrypted Medical Information about a Scout

```
b'gAAAAABcIRmX3txIuOrw6FoSxy7I1vorA8hTTzMcXQGwch_jRBtWTsR9TwVyH125K0R6zG-BTvhv_SpZuW-Hs1WotaabBVj5tQ=='
```

By using this Insert statement

```
    sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO scoutinfo (scoutID, firstname,secondname,age,gender,ethnicity,address,postcode,medicalinfo,parentID,patrolID,userID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
ScoutInput = (
    str(ScoutID), FName.get(), SName.get(), str(Age.get()), str(Gender.get()), str(Ethnicity.get()), Address.get(),
    Postcode.get(), EcryptMedInfo, str(ParentID[0]), str(PatrolID), str(UserID))
mycursor.execute(sqlcommand, ScoutInput)
```

Upon running, the program executes, however the insert is not applied to the table, and no, I have not forgotten about `mydb.commit()`. I believe that `bytes` is an unsupported datatype for MySQL and thus cannot be stored. I that case how would I overcome this, so that I will be able to decrypt the stored token by:

```
Ecy.decrypt(EcryptMedInfo)
```

Comment: It is rare to store anything other than bytes :)

Comment: Haha, you got me there, I meant byte strings.

Comment: Did you mean `b"xxx".decode()`?

Answer (score 2):

If there is `b""` and you want to transform it into string. You should use `decode()` instead of `str()`. Because it is difficult to reverse it if you used `str()`, but it will be easy if you use `decode()`.

```
a = b"\x00\x00"
print((a,a.decode(),str(a)))
print(a == a.decode().encode())
#(b'\x00\x00', '\x00\x00', "b'\\x00\\x00'")
#True
```

> When i use `mysql.connector`, i don't have to transform them into string by myself.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
conn = mysql.connect(user="kr",passwd="kr",db="kr")
cur = conn.cursor()

def go(stat,param=None):
    try:
        cur.execute(stat,param)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        conn.rollback()
        print(e)
go("""
    CREATE TABLE test(
    col varchar(90) NOT NULL
)""")
something = b64encode(b"\x00\x00")
print(something,type(something)) 
go(stat="""INSERT INTO test (col) VALUES (%s)""", param=[something])

cur.execute("SELECT col from test")
result = cur.fetchone()[0]
print([b64decode(result)])
#b'AAA=' <class 'bytes'>
#[b'\x00\x00']
```

> I believe that bytes is an unsupported datatype for MySQL and thus cannot be stored.

Mysql can store it. [Mysql byte array storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309040/mysql-byte-array-storage)